# jQuery Code not loading

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am debugging some jQuery code and have found that the section of code is not firing when clicked.

**My HTML/PHP is:**

`$cartlink .= "<a class='add_to_cart button' data-id='{$product->id}' href='javascript:;' {$style}>{$label}</a>";`

**jQuery:**

```
   <script>
        jQuery(window).on('click', 'a.add_to_cart.button', function() {
        console.log("batman");
    }); 
    </script>
```

Comment: Is the script after the HTML, are there any errors, (other generic debug questions), ?

Comment: Replace `window` with `document`

Comment: @tymeJV Yes it is and no theres not :)

Comment: @RahilWazir Can you post as an answer?  You rock

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to replace the `window` with `document`. Because `window` object doesn't contain DOM Nodes. You however can also do `jQuery(window.document)` to look for DOM Nodes.

[JavaScript Window](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window)

> The window object represents a window containing a DOM document; the document property points to the DOM document loaded in that window